# Ng-repeat in custom directive does not repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying really hard, but I can't find where is my problem.

I created a custom directive and it should iterate some HTML to draw the right content on the screen.

The problem is that my ng-repeat does not iterate my array. I search on stackoverflow but what I found didn't help me.

Here is my directive (it's in an external file):

```
app.directive('logtab', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'view/templates/log-tab.html',
        replace: true,
        controller: ['$scope', 'api', function($scope, api) {
            $scope.logState = false;
            $scope.logData = [1,2,3,4];

            $scope.loadLog = function() {
                api.doRequest({
                    path : $scope.path,
                    method : "GET",
                    broadcast : BK_LOG
                });
            };

            var bk = $scope.$on(BK_LOG, function(key, value){
                $scope.logState = true;
                console.log($scope.logData);

                bk();
            });
        }]
    };
});
```

And here is the directive HTML that will be rendered:

```
<md-tab ng-click="loadLog()" label="{{i18n['REVISIONS']}}">
    <div layout="row" layout-align="center" layout-padding ng-show="!logState">
        <div layout="column">
            <div>
                <md-progress-circular md-mode="indeterminate" md-diameter="130"></md-progress-circular>
            </div>
            <div>
                {{i18n['LOG_LOAD']}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div layout="row" ng-show="logState" layout-padding>
        <div layout="column">
            <div ng-repeat="xyz in logData">
                {{xyz}}
                SOME CONTENT HERE
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</md-tab>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed other components from your directive code and kept it at bare minimum. The code is working fine as expected. Please see below.

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" >


    <logtab></logtab>

    <script src="angular.js" type="text/javascript  "></script>
    <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript  "></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


myApp.directive('logtab', function(){
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'log-tab.html',
    replace: true,
    controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.logState = false;
        $scope.logData = [1,2,3,4];
        console.log('hi');
    }]
};
```

});

**log-tab.html**

```
<div>
{{logData}}
    <div layout="row">
        <div layout="column">
            <div ng-repeat="xyz in logData">
                {{xyz}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please use a couple of console.log's to identify the exact location. I suspect that there must be some thing wrong with the other parts of the directive or may be **logState is set to false**??

Comment: Hello, Naga! In fact you're right! I don't know why, but my friend updated the backend and after getting the new code it worked. I believe something was wrong on the backend, but I still don't know what was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Updated my answer based on OP's explanation.

Created a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/frishi/bzbbo5da/14/

I simplified the directive definition a little, removed the api part of it.
I also changed the directive's template to include the `ng-repeat` part of it.

```
    //....
    restrict: 'E',
    template: `<p><div ng-repeat="xyz in logData">
              {{xyz}}
              SOME CONTENT HERE
               </div></p>`,
    replace: false,
    scope: true, // <- needs to be set
    //....
```

You are missing the `scope` parameter in the directive definition object. You have to set it to `scope: true` for your directive's template to be able to access a variable defined on the directive controller's scope.

Comment: Hello, frishi! Thanks for you answer. I may have been mistaken when explaining. This application is already running, so I know that bootstraping and all other things are right. The ng-repeat I said is inside the directive template. When I put a <logtab><logtab> it doesn't work. Sorry about the bad explanation

Comment: Ooops I hit return my mistake haha

Comment: Updated my answer and the fiddle based on your explanation.

Comment: Hello, frishi! It should iterate the array when I call the directive logtab, not before it.

Comment: My bad, the fiddle link was outdated. The latest fiddle shows it working.

Comment: Frish, I thank you so much by your comments, but the is now working. It seems there were some problem with the backend and the data it was sending to me. Really weird.

Answer (score 0):

You can always separate the controller from the directive:

```
app.directive('logtab', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'view/templates/log-tab.html',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            log: '='
        }
    };
});
```

Then in your controller

```
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'api', function($scope, api) {
    $scope.logTab = {
        state: false,
        data: [1, 2, 3, 4],
        loadLog: function() {
            api.doRequest({
                path : $scope.path,
                method : "GET",
                broadcast : BK_LOG
            });
        }
    };
    var bk = $scope.$on(BK_LOG, function(key, value){
        $scope.logTab.state = true;
        console.log($scope.logTab.data);

        bk();
    });
}]);
```

Then change your HTML to:

```
<md-tab ng-click="log.loadLog()" label="{{i18n['REVISIONS']}}">
    <div layout="row" layout-align="center" layout-padding ng-show="!log.state">
        <div layout="column">
            <div>
                <md-progress-circular md-mode="indeterminate" md-diameter="130"></md-progress-circular>
            </div>
            <div>
                {{i18n['LOG_LOAD']}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div layout="row" ng-show="log.state" layout-padding>
        <div layout="column">
            <div ng-repeat="xyz in log.data">
                {{xyz}}
                SOME CONTENT HERE
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</md-tab>
```

And call it with

```
<logtab log="logTab"></logtab>
```

Comment: Hello @jperezov . But is there any problem with my first code? I don't understand why it does not iterate my array.

Comment: Yeah. The problem is that you're trying to grab variables that are out of the directive's scope. You're supposed to pass data _into_ the directive. If you wanna keep the controller, just keep the function (since that's specific to your directive). Directives are supposed to be reusable, and therefore the data it takes in should be already-formatted data.